# How to solve error while closing command context

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I have created a model in alfresco process model, which contains start event, script task and end event. In the script task I have written the java-script code as `var x=3;
var y=3;
var erg=x*y;
document.write("The result is:"+erg);`.

The code has been successfully validated and published. But once the process gets start it throw out an error in the console as like

```
"ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext  - Error while closing command context
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'document' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)"

08:35:14 [pool-3-thread-1] ERROR org.activiti.engine.impl.asyncexecutor.ExecuteAsyncRunnable  - Job 55008 failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'document' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error and share the knowledge to how to create a script task in a model and execute it.

Comment: You're talking about processes, which implies you're running this on a server. I'm afraid I'm not an alfresco user, but servers don't usually have a document in javascript. Where are you actually expecting to see this output be produced?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343080/how-to-configure-the-alfresco-to-run-a-script-task

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure the alfresco to run a script-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343080/how-to-configure-the-alfresco-to-run-a-script-task)